# SQL statements - Simple text formatting with CONCAT & SUBSTR

Tags: sql, magento, expression, statements

I´m using this piece of software to manage my Magento store https://www.mag-manager.com

It has a feature to mass edit product fields by using SQL expressions as described here: http://store-manager-for-magento-documentation.emagicone.com/products-management/import-products/expression-editor

I have no idea about SQL expressions but I´m getting my head around around them to reformat my SKU numbers. This is the scenario and what I want to achieve:

**Scenario 1**

att_ean = 123456

config_grade = Grade A

config_operator = Vodafone

***Desired result: 123456GAVOD***

---

**Scenario 2**

att_ean = 123456

config_grade = Brand New 0KM

config_operator = Vodafone Spain

***Desired result: 123456BN0VODS***

---

Explanation:

I´d like to use the whole att_ean string.
I´d like to use the first character of each word in config_grade (no matter how many words there are)
I´d like to use the first 3 characters of first word in config_grade and first character of subsequent words (if any)
I´d like all characters to be upper case

This is what I've got so far:

```
CONCAT( [ATTRIBUTE(att_ean)],
substr([ATTRIBUTE(config_grade)], 1, 1),
substr([ATTRIBUTE(config_operator)], 1, 3),
'' )
```

***This is the result for scenario 1: 123456GVod***

***This is the result for scenario 2: 123456BVod***

Answer (score 0):

This uses various SQL functions; `CONCAT`, `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` & `UPPER`

CODE:

```
       CONCAT([att_ean], 
       SUBSTRING([config_grade], 1, 1) + SUBSTRING([config_grade], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_grade]) + 1, 1) + 
       CASE WHEN 0 != CHARINDEX(' ', [config_grade], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_grade]) + 1)
            THEN SUBSTRING([config_grade], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_grade], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_grade]) + 1) + 1, 1) 
            ELSE ''
            END,      
       UPPER(SUBSTRING([config_operator], 1, 3) + SUBSTRING([config_operator], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_operator]) + 1, 1) +
       CASE WHEN 0 != CHARINDEX(' ', [config_operator], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_operator]) + 1)
            THEN SUBSTRING([config_operator], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_operator], CHARINDEX(' ', [config_operator]) + 1) + 1, 1) 
            ELSE ''
            END))
```

OUTPUT:

```
att_ean     config_grade    config_operator  newstring
123456      Grade A         Vodafone         123456GAVODV
123456      Brand New 0KM   Vodafone Spain   123456BN0VODS
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a3b1/6/0

Comment: Hi Matt,Thank you for your reply. I´m afraid it´s not working. It says: Product ID [2913]: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[att_ean]',    SUBSTRING([config_grade], CH' at line 1

Comment: Also note that I used the code I´m showing you above "as is" directly in a software window. I mean without using SELECT. How would you code look like in this case?

Comment: @Pablo post your whole code in your question and i'll work with that

Comment: Matt, that is the whole code. That code is then used in the software which I guess is the reason why I don't need SELECT. The code I posted works as is but it doesn't give me the desired result.

Comment: Similar error: Product ID [2913]: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[att_ean]',    SUBSTRING([config_grade], 1,1) + SUBSTRING([CONFIG_GRADE], CH' at line 1

Comment: According to the software developers there´s a limitation by which I cannot update SKU using SQL expressions. However, I could do it by using a PHP script. I´ll post another question and link it to this post. Thanks a lot Matt!!!